# Configure execution to skip specific tests

Tags: java, maven, junit, categories

I'm creating a test jar with a bunch of JUnit tests on it. Since I'm testing a 3rd part code, I don't run the tests with "mvn test", but I generate an executable jar and run it with "java -jar"

On my tests, I have many different categories, and I'd like to choose which one is executed, which isn't on the command line.
I tried the option -Dgroups="categories", but it does not work with "java -jar"

The thing I want to do is something like that:

```
java -jar -Dcategories="cat1,cat2,cat5" executable.jar
```

The only way I see about reading this on my code is with

```
System.getProperty("categories");
```

I tried using something like that:

```
  @Before
  public void setup() {
    Assume.assumeTrue(System.getProperty("categories") != null && System.getProperty("categories").contains("cat1"));
  }
```

It skips the test but still gives me a stack trace, which looks pretty bad.
Any other option to skip the tests?

Comment: Could you provide the stacktrace?

Comment: Test does not fail, but it gives me something like:

org.junit.AssumptionViolatedException: got: <false>, expected: is <true>
        at org.junit.Assume.assumeThat(Assume.java:95)
        at org.junit.Assume.assumeTrue(Assume.java:41)
...

Answer (score 0):

The [JAVA Documentation says](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/java.html):

java [ options ] -jar file.jar [ argument ... ]

so in your case

**java -jar executable.jar cat1 cat2 cat5**

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    for (String input : args) {
        if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("cat1")) {
            runTests(TestOne.class);
        } else {
            runTests(TestTwo.class);
        }
    }

}

private static void runTests(Class test) {

    Result result = JUnitCore.runClasses(test);
    for (Failure failure : result.getFailures()) {
        System.out.println(failure.toString());
    }
}
```